# $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$. Show that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Recall that
$HK=\{hk:H\in H,k\in K\}$. Show that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$.

Comment: Hint: can you phrase the requirement that $h_1k_1 = h_2k_2$ another way (such elements get counted more than once in enumerating $HK$ as pairs $(h_1,k_1)$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $|H||K|$ is the size of $H \times K$. Define a map $f$ from $H\times K$ to $HK$ by $f:(h,k)\rightarrow hk$. We shall show that for each $x\in HK$, the number of preimages of $x$ in $H\times K$ is $|H\cap K|$; this clearly implies the result.

Suppose that $f(h,k)=hk=x$. Then for any $g\in H\cap K$ we have $x=hgg^{-1}k=f(hg,g^{-1}k)$. It follows that for every element $hg$ of $h(H\cap K)$ there is a preimage of $x$ in $H\times K$ whose $H$ coordinate is $hg$, and so there are at least $|H\cap K|$ preimages. Converesely, if $f(h_1,k_1)$ is preimage of $x$ then $hk=h_1k_1$, and so $h^{-1}h_1=kk_1^{-1}$. Setting $g=h^{-1}h_1$, it is clear that $g\in H\cap K$, and that $h_1=hg$. So all preimages of $x$ have their $H$ coordinate in $h(H\cap K)$ and hence there are at most $|H \cap K|$ preimages. Therefore there are exactly $|H \cap K|$ of them.