# If $G$ is a group of order $96$ and $H,K$ are subgroups of order $12,16$, can $H∩K$ be trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Question**: Given that $G$ is a group of order $96$ and $H$ & $K$ are subgroups of order $12$, $16$ respectively. Then, **is** $H∩K≠\{e\}$ always?

According to me, if $G$ is ablelian then we must have $H∩K≠\{e\}$ because **otherwise** order of $HK$ will be greater than order of group $G$ and we get contradiction. Hence if $G$ is abelian group of order $96$ then we must have $H∩K≠\{e\}$

**But what when $G$ is non-abelian?** Is $H∩K≠\{e\}$ also holds if $G$ is non-abelian? **OR there is some non abelian group of order $96$ such that $H∩K=\{e\}$?** I have been stuck on this problem for hours, can someone please help me?...

Comment: $12 \times 16 > 96$, so the intersection is always nontrivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sir, $HK$ is subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$. Is here we have $HK=KH$? I am confused because, $o(H∩K)$ may be equals to $4$ and we can see $ 4| O(H)$, $4|O(k)$, $4|O(G)$. Please elaborate

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306862/h-and-k-are-subgroups-of-g-show-that-hk-hk-h-cap-k

Comment: It does not matter whether $HK$ is a subgroup. If $H \cap K = \{e\}$ then $|HK| = |H| \times |K|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sir, then is we must always have $|HK| <|G|$ even if $HK$ is not subgroup of $G$, provided $H∩K≠\{e\}$?

Comment: You mean $|HK| \le |G|$. I think you have had enough help with this problem now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that $H\cap K=\{e\}$ is trivial. Consider function

$$f:H\times K\to G$$
$$f(h,k)=hk$$

Then $f$ is injective. Indeed, if $f(h,k)=f(h',k')$ then $h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}$ and since both sides belong to $H$ and $K$ then they are both equal to $e$ meaning $h=h'$ and $k=k'$.

Since $f$ is injective then $|\text{im}(f)|=|H\times K|$ and thus

$$|G|\geq|\text{im}(f)|=|H\times K|=|H|\cdot |K|$$

The first inequality simply follows because $\text{im}(f)$ is a subset of $G$. And so the inequality $|H|\cdot|K|\leq |G|$ and the inequality $12\cdot 16>96$ yield contradiction. Therefore $H\cap K\neq\{e\}$.

Comment: So Sir if I consider any group $G$ and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then $|HK|=|H×K|$ can't be greater than $G$? But i had seen $HK$ need Not be a subgroup of $G$, so why this must be true? :-(

Comment: Sir trying to understand but, not getting it :-(

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I'm not sure what else can I do improve my answer? $HK$ is just a subset, it does not have to be a subgroup. And it doesn't matter. $f$ is not a group homomorphism, is just a function that I use to count elements.

Comment: Sir  then is we must always have $|HK| <|G|$ even if $HK$ is not subgroup of $G$, provided $H∩K≠\{e\}$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi No, we must always have $|HK|\leq |G|$. That's because $HK$ is a subset of $G$. No matter what $H, K$ is. The equality $|HK|=|H\times K|$ follows from $f$ being injective. Please read my answer again because everything you need to know is there.